# Generalization of Chinese Remainder Theorem to infinite ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm looking for any (obviously weaker) generalization of this famous [theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings) in the special case that the family of ideals is not finite.

Comment: Can you specify what kind of conditions you are looking for? E.g. as injectivity of $R/\cap_i I_i \to \prod_i R/I_i$ still holds in the infinite case, under what type of conditions would you like surjectivity to hold?

Comment: Ye, I'm asking for that.

Comment: What I meant was: Do you have a specific hypothesis under which you would like to know if surjectivity holds? Sufficient conditions for surjectivity seem hard to come by - the most obvious one is that $R = \prod_{i \in I} R_i$ itself is an infinite product of rings (and each ideal is "concentrated" in a single component)

Comment: On the other hand, a necessary condition is that surjectivity in the infinite case can never hold if $R$ is Noetherian

Comment: If the natural morphism $f : A \to \prod_{k \in K} A/I_k$ is surjective, then $I_k+I_j = A$ for every $k \neq j$. This is not sufficient in general ; one needs $A$ to be non-Noetherian if $K$ is infinite.

Comment: If $I_j + \bigcap_{k \neq j} I_k = A$, then I think that we have a surjective map ($A$-module morphism?) $A \to \bigoplus_{k \in K} A/I_k$.

Comment: If the natural morphism $f : A \to \prod_{k \in K} A/I_k$ is surjective, then $|A| \geq 2^{|K|}$ (provided that $I_k \neq A$). In particular, a countable ring will satisfy the CRT only with finitely many ideals.

Answer (score 0):

*Getting this out of unanswered-limbo*

---

The key point of the CRT, surjectivity of the map, does not even work for $\mathbb Z$.  This can be seen, as mentioned in the comments, by noting the product cannot is not Noetherian, but also because the product is uncountable.

I would say this does not have a reasonable generalization without further qualification.